# Не корректно отображается шрифт на мобильных устройствах

Tags: css

На bootstrap шаблоне поменял шрифт текста. При открывании сайта на ПК - он отображается корректно и весь текст написан на нужном шрифте. Но, когда открываю сайт с мобильного устройства, то при его адаптации, шрифт не меняется и остаётся стандартным, не тот, что при открывании с ПК.
Пробовал меня стили, но задавать условие, через media screen, но проблема не решена.
Помогите, пожалуйста.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: a_Simpler;
    src: url(../fonts/SIMPLER.ttf)
}
@media screen and (min-width: 1px) {
.head .body .footer {
font-family: a_Simpler;
}
}
```

Вот так оставил, перестал работать вообще и не отображается даже на компьютере.

Comment: Покажите ваш CSS

Comment: https://dropfiles.ru/download/16910acc6928ce71401a610b05bf4bb7.html

Comment: Эм. И где же объявление a_Simpler? Да и вообще посмотрите как правильно писать font-face

Comment: Блин, подскажите, я уже запутался. Он же на ПК отображается а на мобильных почему нет?

Comment: Возможно у вас на ПК он просто установлен в систему

Comment: }
@font-face {
    font-family: a_Simpler;
    src: url(../fonts/SIMPLER.ttf)

Comment: Прописал так, добавил файл шрифтов на сервер - перестало отображатсья даже на компьютере

Comment: Помогите, готов запатить

Comment: Ладно. За косарь подскажу